# Facebook Authentication Finished Open Another App

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Using Facebook authentication, the procedures are that Facebook library will open either Safari/installed Facebook app for executing the authentication and then return back to the app.

I have built multiple apps (Let's say : First App, SecondApp and ThirdApp) and compiled them to my devices. When I tried to authenticating Facebook account, what was happening is that when I finished authenticating Facebook on FirstApp, instead of re-open the same app, it opened SecondApp (sometime ThirdApp).

My hunch is it has something to do with App ID, but I am not sure.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URI scheme is messed up. Also make sure that you have 3 separate apps on Facebook so there will be 3 different URI schemes one for each app.